# How to prevent Visual Studio 2012 from renaming member types (using Entity Framework)?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

In Visual Studio 2012, I have a C# project using the Entity Framework (version 6.1.3).

Everytime I make modifications to the .edmx file and save them, the .cs classes under the .tt file are re-generated. The problem is that I have a table named "System" in the database (not my idea), so everytime the classes are re-generated, Visual Studio places a "System." in front of Guid and DateTime members

Sample code:

```
namespace ProjectName.Data
{
    using global::System;
    using global::System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Area
    {
        public int AreaID { get; set; }
        public int SystemID { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool Enabled { get; set; }
        public System.Guid CreatedByID { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This causes compilation errors because it is looking for the Guid and DateTime members of the Entity object "System", instead of the System namespace. 
So everytime I make a change to the .edmx file, I have to do a Search and Replace in all files to change "System.DateTime" to "DateTime" and "System.Guid" to "Guid", to give the following:

```
namespace ProjectName.Data
{
    using global::System;
    using global::System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Area
    {
        public int AreaID { get; set; }
        public int SystemID { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool Enabled { get; set; }
        public Guid CreatedByID { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Is there an option somewhere in Visual Studio or some way to configure that changing the .edmx file doesn't add those "System." in front of Guid and DateTime types?

**EDIT**:
That is, an option that would stop this behavior without having to rename the System table/class

Thank you

Comment: Rename your `System` entity, that is never a good idea. VS does that for you to differentiate its types from yours when you name it something it also uses. `Message` is another problem.

Comment: I know, but for now I'm stuck with it, so I'm looking for a solution other than changing the entity name. I edited the question to add this specification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats a very common problem with auto generated code and classes that match a namespace name (windows designer does re add the full qualified name as well every time you change something in the designer), just rename the class and save a lot of time.

Comment: For now I'm stuck with the class name, so I'm looking for a solution other than changing the entity name. I edited the question to add this specification